# how to find the number has more than two consecutive appearences?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

The source table:

```
id     num
-------------------
1       1
2       1
3       1
4       2
5       2
6       1
```

The output:(appear at least 2 times)

```
num   times
--------------
1      3
2      2
```

Comment: What's the expected result if you add the row (7,1)?

Comment: times should be the max times that the num appears

Comment: @user618520 . . . What if there is a gap in `id`?

Comment: There is no gap in id currently, thank you for your thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the addition logic defined in the comments it appears this is what you're after:

```
WITH YourTable AS(
    SELECT V.id,
           V.num
    FROM (VALUES(1,1),
                (2,1),
                (3,1),
                (4,2),
                (5,2),
                (6,1),
                (7,1))V(id,num)), --Added extra row due to logic defined in comments
Grps AS(
    SELECT YT.id,
           YT.num,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) -
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Num ORDER BY id) AS Grp
    FROM YourTable YT),
Counts AS(
    SELECT num,
           COUNT(num) AS Times
    FROM grps
    GROUP BY grp,
             num)
SELECT num,
       MAX(times) AS times
FROM Counts
GROUP BY num;
```

This uses a CTE and `ROW_NUMBER` to define the groups, and then an additional CTE to get the `COUNT` per group. Finally you can then get the `MAX` `COUNT` per `num`.

Comment: I do not know who has given a vote down to this but it does work so I will level the things and vote it up.

Answer (score 2):

I would adress this with a gaps-and-islands technique:

```
select num, max(cnt)
from (
    select num, count(*) cnt
    from (
     select 
          id, 
          num, 
          row_number() over(order by id) rn1,
          row_number() over(partition by num order by id) rn2
      from mytable
    ) t
    group by num, rn1 - rn2
) t
group by num
```

The most inner query computes row numbers over the whole table and within `num` groups; the difference between the row numbers gives you the group of adjacent records that each record belong to (you can run that subquery independently and follow how the difference evolves to understand more).

Then, the next level count the number of records in each group of adjacent records. The most outer query takes the maximum count of adjacent records in for each `num`.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=83b695b1ad918bbd056c35070f9cef9e)**:

```
num | (No column name)
--: | ---------------:
  1 |                3
  2 |                2
```

Answer (score -2):

> this will work for you

```
select num,count(num) times from Tabl
group by num
```

Comment: Hi @MohammadShehroz , no it will not work. Check it here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b159778533ba2b439b3a59a6f6b544fa your query is the first one along with results ,and under your query is the one from GMB that works...

Comment: Hello this query working fine you can check https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4a225b788d85dcac784522b8ceed7d54

Comment: As I have shown you in my fiddle it does not. Pleas analyze the data. the result from your fiddle should be 1|3 and 2|2. Please check the comments to this question to understand better what OP (Original Poster) wants. Also, I was not the one that down voted this but now I iwll... Cheers!

Comment: @MohammadShehroz No, you get a `4 times 1`, but the question is about *consecutive appearances* sorted by the id column...